# How can I ask the state for a content object?

Tags: plone

At the end of [this tutorial](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/reference/manipulating-content-objects) several object attributes are listed. But I need access to the state (published, private,...). I also search that attribute using `dir()` but I don't see an attribute named as `state` or something similar. i.e, I need something like this:

```python
>>> app.Plone.foo.bar.state
"published"
```

Comment: Sorry, I will check it today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no "state" attribute. Instead, check `review_state` using the workflow tool e.g.:

```
>>> app.Plone.portal_workflow.getInfoFor(app.Plone.foo.bar, "review_state")
```

Answer (score 9):

Or to keep your code more readable and not having to remember strange method names, you can use [plone.api](http://ploneapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/content.html#get-workflow-state) to do this:

```
from plone import api
api.content.get_state(obj=your_object)
```

Of course, you need to add `plone.api` to your eggs first, and re-run buildout.

Answer (score 5):

You can always use the [plone_workflow](http://developer.plone.org/content/workflow.html) to determine current status:

```
workflowTool = getToolByName(self.portal, "portal_workflow")
status = workflowTool.getStatusOf("plone_workflow", object)
# where "object" is your content object
print (status)
```

Comment: I got `status == None` when asking for the status of `app.Plone.news` when using `bin/instance debug`. Is that OK?

Comment: @DanielHernández: Make sure you have the correct workflow id.

Comment: Your comment implies that there are several workflow state sets? I imagine that I got `None` because the object state is not in the set identified by `"plone_workflow"`.